# How to a get an array of 3D cameras to follow a Bezier curve in unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need to implement a manual Bezier curve script to a camera in my scene. I CANNOT use any methods provided by unity to implement the Bezier curve. I got the formula right but I don't know how to get a camera to follow the curve let alone 4. I could not do an array and just apply the script to each camera if that's an option. I got a lineRenderer script that show the curve:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bezier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public Transform point0, point1, point2, point3;

    private int cPoints = 50;
    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[50];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = cPoints;
        DrawCubicCurve();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DrawCubicCurve();
    }

    private void DrawCubicCurve() 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < cPoints - 1; i++) 
        {
            float t = i / (float)cPoints;
            positions[i - 1] = CalculateCubicBezierCurve(t, point0.position, point1.position, point2.position, point3.position);
        }

        lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
    }
    private Vector3 CalculateCubicBezierCurve(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3) 
    {
        float u = 1 - t;
        float t2 = t * t;
        float uu = u * u;
        float uuu = uu * u;
        float t3 = t2 * t;

        Vector3 p = uuu * p0;
        p += 3 * uu * t * p1;
        p += 3 * u * t2 * p2;
        p += t3 * p3;

        return p;        
    }

}
```

Then I have the script I am trying to make that camera move along such a curve:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamBezier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] cam;
    public Transform point0, point1, point2, point3;

    private float cPoints = 50.0f;
    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[50];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < cam.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            float x = cam[i].transform.position.x;
            float y = cam[i].transform.position.y;
            float z = cam[i].transform.position.z;
        }
        DrawCubicCurve();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DrawCubicCurve();
    }

    private void DrawCubicCurve()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < cam.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            float t = i / (float)cPoints;
            positions[i - 1] = CalculateCubicBezierCurve(t, point0.position, point1.position, point2.position, point3.position);

            cam.transform.position = positions;
        }


    }
    private Vector3 CalculateCubicBezierCurve(float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
    {
        float u = 1 - t;
        float t2 = t * t;
        float uu = u * u;
        float uuu = uu * u;
        float t3 = t2 * t;

        Vector3 p = uuu * p0;
        p += 3 * uu * t * p1;
        p += 3 * u * t2 * p2;
        p += t3 * p3;

        return p;
    }
}
```

Again I CANNOT use any methods provided by unity to implement the Bezier curve. The goal is just to get a camera to move along the Bezier curve. Doing an array of them is extra.

Comment: You have your `CalculateCubicBezierCurve()`, can you Lerp `t` in coroutine from 0 to 1 and set result Vector3 to `camera.transform.position`?

Comment: I cannot use lerp

Comment: Just increment some value in Update by `Time.deltaTime`, pass it to that function and assign resulted Vector3 to camera position